# Docker container can reach DNS but not resolve hosts

Tags: linux, dns, docker, fedora-21

I'm having an interesting problem running docker containers: out of the blue, I'm not able to resolve DNS from within the container.

Here's a rundown:

1. Nothing is resolving; apt-get, pip, one-off ping containers, etc. Running `docker run -it --dns=8.8.8.8 ubuntu ping www.google.com` results in `ping: unknown host www.google.com` both with and without the `--dns` flag.
2. I can reach 8.8.8.8 both from inside and outside the containers.  `docker run -it ubuntu ping 8.8.8.8` works.
3. I've configured the containers to use both 8.8.8.8, 8.8.8.4, and my local network DNS servers (in various permutations) both by editing `/etc/sysconfig/docker` to add `DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.8.4"` and by setting the `--dns 8.8.8.8` flag on the containers at runtime. `systemctl restart docker` was run between each change.
4. `ip_forward` is enabled. (see [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/490))
5. I've done a full reset as specified [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/866#issuecomment-19218300).

I'm running Fedora 21, docker client version 1.5.0.

Any ideas? I'm at a complete loss as to what's preventing docker from accessing the Internet successfully.

Comment: Perhaps you should open an issue in the docker issue tracker; https://github.com/docker/docker/issues. When doing so, please include the relevant information as explained here https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: Same here with fedora 22.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have fixed the issue in 1.8: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13381 Cheers.

Comment: Could you link to the fix for posterity?

Comment: Yeah, link was a pain to re-find lol. I really need to start tracking the Q&A of my problems for reference.

Answer (score 1):

After all this, a full reboot solved the problem - although, that still doesn't answer what it was.

If anyone knows what the actual cause was, I'm still curious, but for now the problem is gone.

Comment: I'm having the problem repeatedly, reboot helps but can't be the solution. The problem doesn't just occur with the ubuntu image, but all I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You could install tools like `dig`  inside the docker image to alanyse the issue.

use static hosts in your `/etc/hosts` file te make apt-get run inside the docker image. add these lines to your hosts file:

```
213.32.5.7 debian.mirrors.ovh.net
141.76.2.4 ftp.de.debian.org 
217.196.149.233 mirror-conova-security.debian.org
212.211.132.250 lobos.debian.org
212.211.132.250 security.debian.org 
5.153.231.4  http.debian.net 
151.101.12.204 cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org
151.101.12.204 security-cdn.debian.org
```